# Verifying that an Android banking app checks that the certificate is trusted

Tags: tls, certificates, mobile, vpn, banks

I have a closed source banking app on my **unrooted** Android phone. I'd like to verify the following:

- The app uses SSL to communicate with the server
- The app verifies that the SSL certificate of the server is trusted

To this end I set up a [VPN server with racoon and xl2tpd](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/AndroidVPNServer). I am sniffing the network traffic using wireshark and can thus verify that the app uses SSL.

For the second point, I was thinking I could simply set up a web server with a self-signed certificate for `bank.com`, make my phone use that one, and see if it complains. Of course, my server won't respond adequately, but I'm hoping I will see `Untrusted certificate` as error message in the app rather than `Unknown error occurred`.

I edited `/etc/hosts` to let `bank.com` have `127.0.0.1` and set up my server. However, my phone still uses the actual IP. So, apparently, xl2tpd doesn't use `/etc/hosts`. How can I let xl2tpd think `bank.com` is at `127.0.0.1`?

Or, alternatively, how do I verify the second point above, if there is a better way?

Comment: Which /etc/hosts file did you edit? Editing the one on the Android device should be sufficient. Why do you need the VPN?

Comment: @NeilSmithline sorry, I should have clarified that I'm working with an unrooted phone, so I can't edit its /etc/hosts. The idea was that with the VPN I could sniff all traffic (useful for point 1). Then I tried to extend it to verify point 2.

Comment: A proxy is better for that. I think if you configure this proxy but skip the SSL cert configuration you should get your answer. https://medium.com/@rotxed/how-to-debug-http-s-traffic-on-android-7fbe5d2a34#.a33o75ueo

Comment: @NeilSmithline thanks very much, this worked excellent. Would you mind writing an answer for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proxy is better for that. I think if you configure [this proxy](https://medium.com/@rotxed/how-to-debug-http-s-traffic-on-android-7fbe5d2a34#.a33o75ueo) but skip the SSL cert configuration you should get your answer.